# How to insert a column from another table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have two tables I need to merge without creating a new view/table. Basically, I need to add only one column to an existing table taken from another table.

`table1` looks like this:
[image]

`table2` looks like this: 
[image]

I need to get a table that would look just like `table2` but with an additional column: `programs_total`. If there is no such `id` in the first column, I want the second column to have `NULL`. In this example, I want the raw with `id=72_200` to have `NULL` in the `programs_total` column.

I tried the following script:

```
-- adding a new column 
ALTER TABLE table2
ADD programs_total BIGINT NULL;

-- inserting new data
INSERT INTO table2 (programs_total)
SELECT programs_total
FROM table1
```

but it produces the following error:

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'stb.dbo.table2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I suppose it tries to insert three new rows instead of joining the column with the existing ones. How do I tell it to join the column to the existing rows?

Or maybe I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: Seems like you want an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`, not an `INSERT`. Or can there be rows for a value of `id` in` table1` that don't appear in `table2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like what you *really* want an `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE t2
SET t2.total_programs = t1.total_programs
FROM dbo.table2 t2
     JOIN dbo.table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

If, however, you could have values of `id` in `table1` that don't appear in `table2` and you want to insert those values into `table2` as well you'll want a `MERGE`:

```sql
MERGE dbo.Table2 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS T2 
USING dbo.TAble1 AS T1 ON T2.id = T1.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET total_programs = t1.total_programs
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id,total_programs)
    VALUES(T1.id,T1.total_programs);
```

Or you could write it as an Upsert as follows:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE t2 WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) 
SET t2.total_programs = t1.total_programs
FROM dbo.table2 t2
     JOIN dbo.table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id;

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(id,total_programs)
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.total_programs
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: @Larnu The second solution, where you roll your own Upsert seems to be a bit safer; personally, I've shied away from using `MERGE` after reading the following from Aaron Betrand: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 1):

> Description: you need an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. The former will add a *new* row, hence your error for non-nullable columns

Try the following to test, and if it looks good, run the `UPDATE` statement:

```
SELECT 
     t2.*
    ,table1.programs_total   /* new column*/
FROM table2 t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 on t2.ID = table1.id  ;
```

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t2
SET total_programs = table1.programs_total
FROM table2 t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 on t2.ID = table1.id  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can get the data with:

```
SELECT 
    table2.id,
    table2.total_duration,
    table1.programs_total
FROM
    table2
    LEFT JOIN table1
    ON table2.id = table1.id
```

And if you need this data as a new table, you can simply add an INTO like this:

```
SELECT 
    table2.id,
    table2.total_duration,
    table1.programs_total
INTO
    table3
FROM
    table2
    LEFT JOIN table1
    ON table2.id = table1.id
```

With 'table3' being the name of the new table.

Comment: the OP doesn't want a new table, just an added field to table 2

Comment: To quote: "I need to get a table that would look just like table2" I think my solution is applicable here.

Comment: Read the first line - *without creating a new view/table*. Your solution will find the correct matches, though there's the new object which doesn't seem to be something which the OP wants to have

Comment: Ah I missed that, fair enough - i'll leave my answer up in case it's helpful but I can delete it at the discretion of OP.

Comment: @HarryClark Still thanks for your answer! It would really solve my problem, but the answer by Larnu is exactly what I was looking for. Let's leave your answer here in case it is useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update that column:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET total_programs = B.total_programs
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking question with such details. You can also use subquery to update table2.

```
update table2
set programs_total=(select programs_total from table1 where table1.id=table2.id)
```